# Javascript Select Children of Children?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way in Javascript not in jQuery to select the children of a children node ?
For Example i want to select the `<LI>` where the offset parent is.

```
<li class="all_leagues"> ?
```

Example:

```
    <li class="top_leagues">
     <h5>Top Ligen</h5>
     <ul class="games first">
     <ul class="games">
     <ul class="games">
    </li>
    <li class="all_leagues">
     <h5>Alle Ligen</h5>
     <ul class="games first">
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_15231" class="league_check ">
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_15175" class="league_check ">
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_12214" class="league_check ">
    </ul>
    <ul class="games">
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_16106" class="league_check ">
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_13939" class="league_check ">
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_16419" class="league_check ">
    </ul>
    <ul class="games">
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_14823" class="league_check ">
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_11940" class="league_check ">
    </ul>
   </li>
```

and ho could i select the id's from the returned node list ?
Actually i get `li#lg_chk_br_1_l_14481.league_check`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll('.all_leagues > ul > li')
```

Note: [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility)(for the above IE8+ should work)

Or

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.all_leagues .league_check');
for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
  console.log(list[i].id)
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="top_leagues">
    <h5>Top Ligen</h5>
    <ul class="games first"></ul>
    <ul class="games"></ul>
    <ul class="games"></ul>
  </li>
  <li class="all_leagues">
    <h5>Alle Ligen</h5>
    <ul class="games first">
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_15231" class="league_check "></li>
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_15175" class="league_check "></li>
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_12214" class="league_check "></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="games">
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_16106" class="league_check "></li>
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_13939" class="league_check "></li>
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_16419" class="league_check "></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="games">
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_14823" class="league_check "></li>
      <li id="lg_chk_br_1_l_11940" class="league_check "></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much =) fiddeling about 2 hours =) but is there a possibility to but the output into a var ?

Comment: i was trying `var click = list[i].id `but i get an error

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed it ;) 
Forgot that
`var list = document.getElementsByClassName("all_leagues")` returns an Array so the right selector is
`var list = document.getElementsByClassName("all_leagues")[0];`

full code:

`var list = document.getElementsByClassName("all_leagues")[0];
list.getElementsByClassName("league_check ");`

thx anyways ;)

Comment: "returns an Array" — It's a NodeList, not an Array.